Get the default Toolset name for Visual Studio Generators in cMake
I have a cmake project for building a shared C++ library on Windows. There I would like to append the PlatformToolset information to the libraries file name.
I know the cMake variable CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET where the Platform Toolset is defined when it is specified with the configuration command. e.g.: cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -T v141 .
Unfortunately the CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET variable is not defined when the default toolset (-T option not specified) is used.
Is there any way to get the default toolset information in my CMakeLists.txt file? Or does I have to manually define the Toolset information based on the MSVC_VERSION?

The default MSVC toolset corresponds to the Visual Studio version.
Visual Studio 2015: v140
Visual Studio 2017: v141
Visual Studio 2019: v142
Visual Studio 2022: v143


append the PlatformToolset information to the libraries file name.

Use macro : $(PlatformToolset) for output name.
Such as
 set_target_properties(MyExecutable PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME "MyExecutable_$(PlatformToolset)"
)



I just found another cMake variable which contains the right version: ${MSVC_TOOLSET_VERSION} contains the version number (e.g. 142).
I use this variable to define the library file name. Compared to $(PlatformToolset) it is defined and evaluated in cMake.
